# After ajax post in mvc url is so long

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

```
http://localhost:53435/Blog/BlogIndex?title=blog+title&seo=seo&content=%3Cp%3Econtent%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A
```

the url as above

when i click save button page is refresh and url like that

i dont want it how can i fix it ??

my controller code

```
try
            {
                Blog addModel = new Blog();
                content = content.Replace("<p>", "").Replace("</p>", "");
                addModel.BlogPictureURL = pictureData;
                addModel.BlogContent = content;
                addModel.BlogPictureSEO = seo;
                addModel.BlogTitle = title;
                addModel.BlogDate = DateTime.Today;
                addModel.BlogViewCount = 0;
                db.Blog.Add(addModel);
                db.SaveChanges();

                var lastID = db.Blog.OrderByDescending(x => x.ID).Take(1).FirstOrDefault().ID;
                foreach (var item in Tags)
                {
                    Tags newTag = new Tags();
                    newTag.TagsName = item;
                    newTag.BlogID = lastID;
                    db.Tags.Add(newTag);
                }

                db.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("BlogIndex", "Blog");
            }
            catch
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Error", "Admin");
            }
```

my ajax code

```
function SaveAllData() {
        var blogFile;

        var elem = $(".dz-details").find("img");

        blogFile = elem[0].getAttribute("alt");

        var elemData = $("#tags").val();

        elemData = elemData.split(",");

        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "/Blog/AddBlog",
            datatype: "json",
            traditional: true,
            data: {
                title: $("#title").val(),
                seo: $("#seo").val(),
                content: CKEDITOR.instances.content.getData(),
                Tags: elemData,
                pictureData: blogFile
            }

        });
}
```

if i do this without ajax post there was no problem 
but do with ajax something wrong

Comment: how is `SaveAllData` being called ?

Comment: <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="float:right" onclick="SaveAllData()"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> Save</button like this

Comment: The whole point of ajax is to stay on the same page and ajax calls never redirect so your `return RedirectToAction(...)` lines of code make no sense. Since you want to redirect, DO NOT use ajax - make a normal submit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your form is still doing a normal form submit instead of the ajax post. This happens when you have some javascript code to do an ajax submission on the submit button click of a form, but forgot to stop the default behavior, which is the form submission on the submit button click. From the url you posted it looks like, your form method is also a GET, which submits data via querystring.

You just need to make sure you are not letting the default behavior happen.

Here is the unobutrusive way of binding the click event to your button

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="float:right" id="btnSubmit">
```

and the js code

```
function SaveAllData() {
  // your existing code for the ajax call
}
$(function(){
   $("#btnSubmit").click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();  // This will prevent the default form submit
       SaveAllData();
   });
});
```

Also, If it is an ajax form submit, it does not makes sense to return a RedirectResult. You may consider returning a json structure with the url value to navigate to (if needed).

Comment: Resolved url problem thank you but data doesn't come to data table without renewing the page

Comment: That is the expected behavior because you are doing an ajax post(no page reload).You need to update the DOM on the `success` callback of your ajax call with the new data.

Comment: success: function () {
                            window.location.href("/Blog/BlogIndex");
                        },  is this wrong ?

Comment: that will do a new browser request to that url.

Comment: what you want to update in the DOM ? It looks like you want to redirect to the index page. you can do that by `windows.location.href='/blog/blogindex;`

Comment: $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "/Blog/AddBlog",
            //datatype: "json",
            traditional: true,
            data: {
                title: $("#title").val(),
                seo: $("#seo").val(),
                content: CKEDITOR.instances.content.getData(),
                Tags: elemData,
                pictureData: blogFile
            },
            success: function () {
            windows.location.href = '/Blog/BlogIndex';
        }

Comment: but insert is successfull